# how to make Visual Studio to auto complete npm modules methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

I recently started following a course about Node JS. I have an issue on the VS Code being that autocomplete doesn't provide me with npm modules method suggestions. (See the example of the validator npm module). Some users report having such issues with VS code. Is there a way to solve this? 
[VS Code issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T1VW.png)

**Update**
I noticed that VS Code suggests a default option which can be selected to get the package name. However, when running the code, I need to remove that or I will get errors. 
[image]

[image]